# where condition failed on multiple inner joins in sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to inner join multiple columns but resulted in invalid column on where condition.
Query:

```
select t_contract,t_complete,t_zone_name, t_street_name, t_vrm, t_make, t_model,t_colour,t_date_finally_settled,t_cancelled,t_offence_code,
    t_date_time_issued,    CONVERT(VARCHAR, t_date_time_issued, 103) as date_issued,   CONVERT(VARCHAR, t_date_time_issued, 108) AS time_issued,   te_event, lhr.*  
        FROM tickets t  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN   
         (  
         SELECT DISTINCT thr.thr_system_ref, hr.hr_description AS latest_on_hold_reason  
                FROM dbo.tickets t  
                INNER JOIN dbo.ticket_hold_record thr  
                ON (t.t_number=thr.thr_system_ref)  
                INNER JOIN  
                (  
                    SELECT mthr.thr_system_ref, MAX(mthr.thr_on_hold_date) AS m_thr_on_hold_date  
                    FROM dbo.ticket_hold_record mthr  
                    GROUP BY mthr.thr_system_ref  
                ) latest  
                ON (thr.thr_system_ref=latest.thr_system_ref AND thr.thr_on_hold_date=latest.m_thr_on_hold_date)  
                INNER JOIN dbo.hold_reasons hr    " ON (thr.thr_hold_type=hr.hr_code) where hr_code in (' 2260675','2793360','2810778','2903324','2420135')
                ON (thr.thr_hold_type=hr.hr_code)  
            )lhr  
            ON (t.t_number=lhr.thr_system_ref)  

         Inner JOIN  
           ticket_events  te  
         ON ( t.t_number = te.te_system_ref)  

        where  thr.thr_hold_type = '2420135' 
        and  convert (datetime,te_date,101) between convert(datetime,'2015/11/01',101)
           and convert (datetime,'2015/11/25',101)
```

Error:
The column prefix 'thr' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

Comment: Simply remove one condition at the time, and see when it executes without an error. Then you can correct it. (Hint:  where  thr.thr_hold_type = '2420135' ... Move into sub-query.)

Comment: the thr table isn't visible from your outer select. You should put the condition on the query that selects from this table

Comment: Jarlh there is  only one condition and that column is from multiple inner joins and i used latest,lhr  alias names but still failing.

Comment: Why can't you have thr.thr_hold_type = '2420135' as the sub-query's WHERE.

Comment: i need to use that column in where condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same query as before, but I've moved the `thr.thr_hold_type = '2420135'` condition into the sub-query to get into scope (and also not mess with distinct):

```
select t_contract,t_complete,t_zone_name, t_street_name, t_vrm, t_make, t_model,t_colour,t_date_finally_settled,t_cancelled,t_offence_code,
    t_date_time_issued,    CONVERT(VARCHAR, t_date_time_issued, 103) as date_issued,   CONVERT(VARCHAR, t_date_time_issued, 108) AS time_issued,   te_event, lhr.*  
        FROM tickets t  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN   
         (  
         SELECT DISTINCT thr.thr_system_ref, hr.hr_description AS latest_on_hold_reason  
                FROM dbo.tickets t  
                INNER JOIN dbo.ticket_hold_record thr  
                ON (t.t_number=thr.thr_system_ref)  
                INNER JOIN  
                (  
                    SELECT mthr.thr_system_ref, MAX(mthr.thr_on_hold_date) AS m_thr_on_hold_date  
                    FROM dbo.ticket_hold_record mthr  
                    GROUP BY mthr.thr_system_ref  
                ) latest  
                ON (thr.thr_system_ref=latest.thr_system_ref AND thr.thr_on_hold_date=latest.m_thr_on_hold_date)  
                INNER JOIN dbo.hold_reasons hr  
                ON (thr.thr_hold_type=hr.hr_code)  
                WHERE thr.thr_hold_type = '2420135' 
            )lhr  
            ON (t.t_number=lhr.thr_system_ref)  

         Inner JOIN  
           ticket_events  te  
         ON ( t.t_number = te.te_system_ref)  

        where convert (datetime,te_date,101) between convert(datetime,'2015/11/01',101)
           and convert (datetime,'2015/11/25',101)
```

Comment: Thanks I have updated my code the inner join has multiple conditions and i should use that  particular column on where condition..

Comment: Great to hear you've got it!